# OTA SMS in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, sms

I know OTA SMS are not supported in every country but in some countries they are still applicable. I wonder to know if the android OS supports OTA SMS  (old black and white photo SMS)?
If yes then how can we send these SMS?

Comment: By OTA, do you mean WiFi or Cellular connection?

Comment: No old picture messages were in .ota format you can have an example of these messages here http://www.cell11.com/picture_message/message1.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to Nokia's "Smart Messaging"; specifically [OTA bitmap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OTA_bitmap)s.  They were never very well supported outside of Nokia handsets,  I don't believe any android handsets support them.

Answer (score 0):

Over the Air term is consisting different functionalities from recipient perspective. If recipient is Android device itself, OTA messages are used to update the system, application or time zones. Those SMSs are being sent from source system as binary SMS with different data coding scheme. MMS is also one of them.

Android OTA binary SMS packets are not encrypted/signed with SIM OTA keys. OTA messages also can be used for updating SIM files or upload/modify applications on SIM. Recipient of those SMS are SIM card and they have to be sent by entity having OTA SIM Keys or in another words by GSM operator. OTA Secret Keys are very critical and never shared by GSM operators with 3rd parties.

MMS messages are delivered with combination of SMS and WAP technologies. Device receives first WAP Push as binary SMS. This notification contains header information about the MMS message, and a URL pointer that the recipient must fetch in order to retrieve the content of the MMS message.

Android OTA messages can be received by device while its is either connected to Wifi or mobile data. But OTA messages addressing to SIM card can be send only using GSM operators' SMS bearer.